# Why my nginx config for hiding jsp extension doesn't work properly?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, hide

I configure my Nginx web server with follow setting, It hides .jsp extension but doesn't appear my page.

```
        location ~ \.(jsp)$ {
        proxy_pass   http://192.168.2.225:9595;
         if ($request_filename ~* ^(.*).jsp$)
       {
              rewrite ^/(.*).jsp$ /$1 redirect;
               break;
        }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ \.jsp {
    return 403;
}
```

That will make *.jsp inaccessible. If you want them accessible but only via internal rewrites, then change the 'return 403;' to 'internal;'.